# How can i extract a line from a PHP array that returns multiple strings

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have a PHP variable named $user, i set the variable like this:

```
$user = $e->getUser();
```

When i echo $user i receive the following data in an array:

```
Array
(
    [user_id] => 1
    [login] => test
    [pass] => ***
    [remember_key] => 
    [pass_dattm] => 2019-10-11 19:35:08
    [email] => test@test.com
    [name_f] => test
    [name_l] => test
    [street] => 
    [street2] => 
    [city] => 
    [state] => 
    [zip] => 
)
```

I want to echo just the value of 'login' to a file using exec, however i have tried different solutions found on stackoverflow but it does not seem to work for me.
I have tried:

```
$user = $e->getUser();
exec("echo '".$user['login']."' >> /tmp/test");
```

and also tried :

```
$user = $e->getUser()->login();
exec("echo '".$user."' >> /tmp/test");
```

However both return a blank variable.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Does a simple `echo $user['login'];` work?

Comment: I can not directly access the file, so i have to echo it to a tmp file to see if its working, but exec("echo '".$user['login']."' >> /tmp/test"); does not work

Comment: Can you do var_dump($user); and add whole result of var_dump to question?

Comment: Why does it have to be using exec? That doesn't feel safe.

Comment: I am just testing at the moment i will be changing to file put contents

Answer (score 3):

You should use `escapeshellarg()` to ensure that it's properly escaped.

```
$user = $e->getUser();
$login = escapeshellarg($user['login']);
exec("echo $login >> /tmp/test");
```

But there's little reason to use `exec()` for this, since PHP can write to files itself.

```
file_put_contents("/tmp/test", $user['login'] . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: This does not extract the 'login' string, it dumps the whole array

Comment: Oops, fixed that.